# Repitition of a query in sql server from C#.NET Winform application

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i want to run the same query ten times.

```
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('item_name')

GO 10
```

i can use GO , but i want to do this from my .net winform application. when the user clicks a button then the query gets executed and inserts 10 rows into the table ITEMS.
whats the solution for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this in your C# code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The `GO` is **not** a valid SQL keyword - it's a SQL Server Management Studio addition that works only in SSMS (and btw: you can rename that to anything you like in the SSMS options dialog - try renaming it to `SELECT` and have some fun :-) )

Comment: sir , when GO can't be used from C# application, then in real applications , is there any use of it? like developers do use it, if yes, then where?

Comment: @sqlchild: "GO" is used in SSMS - and only there.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop to your insert command

Answer (score 1):

In straight SQL:

```
DECLARE @I INT

SET @I = 0

WHILE (@I < 10)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO items VALUES ('item_name')
   SET @I = @I + 1
END
```